# In a sql query I want to output one column as a json array of child values

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql

I have a product table that I query for various fields. There is a ProductTagMapping table that assigns several tags to each product. I would like to add a Tags column to my output row that contains a JSON Array of the associated Tag Names from a ProductTag table. So the result would be:

```
ProductId: 0
ProductName: Pretty Necklace
Tags: ["gold", "topaz", "fire"]
```

With a join I would get many identical product rows for each tag:

```
SELECT p.ProductId, p.ProductName. pt.TagName
FROM Product AS p
INNER JOIN ProductTagMapping as ptm ON ptm.ProductId = p.ProductId
INNER JOIN ProductTag as pt ON pt.TagId = ptm.TagId
```

I found an almost answer, but it's not correct:

```
SELECT      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY p.SKU) AS Id,
        p.Id AS ProductId,
        p.Name AS ProductName,
        REPLACE(REPLACE((SELECT
                pt.Name as TagNames
                FROM
                ProductTag AS pt
                INNER JOIN
                    dbo.Product_ProductTag_Mapping as ptm ON ptm.Product_Id = p.Id AND ptm.ProductTag_Id = pt.Id                        
                WHERE
                ptm.Product_Id = p.Id
                ORDER BY
                pt.Name
            FOR
                JSON AUTO
            ), N'{"pt.Name":', N''), '"}', '"') AS [Tags]
```

FROM           dbo.Product AS p WITH (NOLOCK)

Which yields:

```
"productid": 8,
"productName": "Gold Tone Earrings",
"tags": "[{\"TagNames\":\"blue\",{\"TagNames\":\"clipon\",{\"TagNames\":\"gold\"]"
```

How would I approach creating the Tags column correctrly?
Thanks
Abbott

Comment: SELECT p.ProductId, p.ProductName, (SELECT pt.TagName ... JSON ... etc) FROM Something

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks alright, but you need to do a JSON_QUERY on your "replace"-string, otherwise it will JSON-ize it as a string which you don't want.
See my version below for what i mean. You also replace wrong word, you probably ment: REPLACE(..., "TagNames", '').

This stuff is if you're using older SQL Server that doesn't support creating arrays or STRING_AGGs. The 2022 has support for creating arrays directly:

```sql
create table #products (productid int, productname nvarchar(100))
create table #producttag (productid int, tagid int)
create table #tag (tagid int, tagname nvarchar(100))

insert into #products
values  (1, 'Earring')
,   (2, 'Blouse')

insert into #tag
values  (1, 'Gold')
,   (2, 'Metal')
,   (3, 'Blue')
,   (4, 'Red')

insert into #producttag
VALUES  (1, 1)
,   (1, 2)
,   (1, 3)
,   (2, 4)

select productid, productname,
  JSON_QUERY(stuff((select ',"' + STRING_ESCAPE(tagname, 'json') + '"'
   FROM #producttag pt
   INNER JOIN #tag t
      ON t.tagid = pt.tagid
   WHERE pt.productid = p.productid
   for xml path(''), type
   ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '[') + ']') tags
from #products p
for json path
```

I don't like replaces, so instead I create the array string manually by using xml path, and then converts it into a json array.

Comment: siggemannen - Thank you so much. It worked like a charm.
Abbott

Comment: I may have asked for the wrong thing. This is for an api. I'm using swagger, which takes the raw results: 

["topaz","green","blue","silver"]


and produces:

"tags": "[{\"TagNames\":\"blue\",{\"TagNames\":\"green\",{\"TagNames\":\"silver\",{\"TagNames\":\"topaz\"]"

Comment: I may have asked for the wrong thing. This is for an api. I'm using swagger, which takes the raw results: 

["topaz","green","blue","silver"]


and produces:

"tags": "[{\"TagNames\":\"blue\",{\"TagNames\":\"green\",{\"TagNames\":\"silver\",{\"TagNames\":\"topaz\"]"
Should it be wrapped in {"Tags": [ .... ] }. and if so, how can this be added to what's there?

 I tried -      ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '{tags:[') + ']}') tags

but it threw JSON text not formatted properly when I ran the view.
There is a very big hole in my knowledge base ... 
Thanks - Abbott